# exclude disabled fields from required laravel validation

Tags: laravel

How can i exclude disabled fields from the required fields when dealing with validation?

I don't know witch fields are going to be disabled this is happening Dynamic

```
<input type="text" name="modul" value="" placeholder="" disabled="disabled">
```

How to check in the validation for **disabled="disabled"** fields and exclude them from validation

```
 $this->validate($request, [
      modul => 'required'  // make not required if filed is disabled
 ]);
```

Comment: you can pass a hidden field with every dissabled field to check it in controller
like `<input type="hidden" name="modul_validate" value="" >`
and `<input type="hidden" name="modul_validate" value="required" >` if not disabled and use in controller
`$this->validate($request, [
      modul => $request->module_validate  // make not required if filed is disabled
 ]);`

Comment: i could have up to 30 disabled fields, i need good solution and an example please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `sometimes` validation rule.

```
 $this->validate($request, [
  'modul' => 'sometimes|required'
]);
```

[Conditionally Adding Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

Comment: That's what i needed! Boom.

Comment: @Edo So, you can accept it as right answer if it's helpful;)

Comment: you have it. :)